# how to pass input data to another php through ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with this?

I have an index page where the user will input 2 dates and send it through ajax to another php page namely month.php. month.php will then use those user inputted dates in the mysql query and select data from the database. My method doesn't seem to work.

index.php

```
<SCRIPT>
        function loadMonth()
        {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                  }
            else
                  {// code for IE6, IE5
                  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
                  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                    document.getElementById("myDivs").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
              }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","month.php",true);
            xmlhttp.send(); 
        }
</SCRIPT>

<div class="form" align="center">
        Select Dates<br>
        <input type="date" name="date1" ><br><br>
        To<br>
        <input type="date" name="date2" ><br><br>
        <input type="submit" onclick="loadMonth()" value="Search">
        <div id="myDivs"></div>
</div>
```

month.php

```
<?php
        $getdate1 = $_POST['date1'];
        $getdate2 = $_POST['date2'];
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "table1");

            // Check connection
        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                }

            $today = date("Y-m-d");
            $sql = "SELECT items, COUNT(*) as Number
            FROM table1
            WHERE (date_table BETWEEN '".$getdate1."' AND '".$getdate2."')
            GROUP BY items";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
```

My code doesn't seem to be working

Comment: You have tagged this with jQuery but are using native javascript ajax calls. I might suggest using jQuery's builtin `.ajax` functionality as it will simply things alot.

Comment: Could this be your problem? `xmlhttp.open("GET","month.php",true);` **-** `$getdate1 = $_POST['date1'];`  GET method in ajax but POST method on  the php?

Comment: sorry, i just tagged it because it was in the recommendation

Comment: so i should change the xmlhttp.open("GET","month.php",true); to xmlhttp.open("POST","month.php",true); ?

Comment: Do you want to post data or do you want to get data... Think about your question and take a little more time reading sample code when you use it. It's a simple error to make but if you use copy/paste source code it's always important to read it, understand it so you can change it to fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below code in your open method

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","month.php?date1=yourdate&date2=yourdate",true);
```

date1 and date2 are being recieved using GET method so in server side you should have:

```
    $getdate1 = $_GET['date1'];
    $getdate2 = $_GET['date2'];
```

**Edited:**

I am also showing that how will you pick up the date values from the input type using

In your html give id attribute to the input fields, so that it becomes easy to access in javascript

```
 <input type="date" name="date1" id = "iddate1" ><br><br>
 <input type="date" name="date2" id = "iddate2" ><br><br>
```

your script part:

```
    var fdate1 = document.getElementById('iddate1').value;
    var fdate2 = document.getElementById('iddate2').value;

    xmlhttp.open("GET","month.php?date1="+fdate1+"&date2="+fdate2,true);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not sending any parameters to the month.php, you can send it using GET Method like this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","month.php?date1=someDate&date2=anotherDate",true);
```

And in the PHP Code :

```
$getdate1 = $_GET['date1'];
$getdate2 = $_GET['date2'];
```

Or using POST Method:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","month.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("date1=someDate&date2=anotherDate");
```

And keeping the php code like it is.

> IMPORTANT: Make sure that you escape the values before using it in the
>   SQL Query  or use prepared statements otherwhise you are vulnerable
>   to SQL Injection.

You should search for 'Prevent SQL Injection PHP'

Comment: what should i put in the someDate and anotherDate?

Comment: you should put the values that you want to send

Comment: @ewfheufcwqqrew you will want to get the values of your input elements that you wish the send via ajax to your php file...

Comment: @ecarrizo I agree with your edit. If i'm honest I think ewfheufcwqqrew should spend some more time researching the source code to get a better understanding of what the source code is doing. Using server-side languages is great but can put your website at risk if you don't be careful.

Comment: @NewToJS agree, I hope that if someone copy the question code, see the advice. Because most of poeple copy code examples like they are without wondering what they are actually doing. .

Comment: Anyone can copy/paste from the internet but not knowing what it is you're using is never a good idea and it could be insecure/malicious or if it randomly stops working that person won't have a clue how to fix it. Sample source is for people to build/expand on. Some comments can feel harsh but I see many posts like this and I know this person is looking for copy/paste hence no answer submitted, just hints on where to look to edit/fix.